# <p:inputText> value not updated in model on change

Tags: jsf, primefaces, in-place-editor

I have a form that lets me edit a list of beans (one at a time), using buttons I can switch between the beans.

Keeping it simple :

```
public class MyBean {
   private String text;
}

public class MyController {
   private List<MyBean> availableBeans = new ArrayList<MyBean>(); // has five MyBeans with random text
   private MyBean selectedBean; // initialized with first element of list

   private int index = 0;

   public void nextBean() { index++; }
   public void previousBean() { index--; }

   private void refreshBean() { selectedBean = availableBeans.get(index); }
}
```

For the html part I have something like

```
<h:form id="someForm">
   <!-- stuff -->

    <p:inputText value="#{myController.selectedBean.text}" />

    <p:inplace editor="true" label="#{myController.selectedBean.text}" >
        <p:inputText value="#{myController.selectedBean.text}" />
    </p:inplace>

   <!-- more stuff-->
</h:form>
```

If I change the text inside the inplace tag, the variable in myBean will be updated just fine, but If I only use inputText the bean will still have the old value, even if I change it on the webpage. Why is that?

Comment: Please do not use Stack Overflow question editor as code editor. Edit (and test!) it in a true editor and then copypaste code unmodified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because the `p:inplace editor="true"` implicitly submits the value to the server while `<p:inputText` does not do it implicitly,

You can solve it in several ways

1) add submit button like `<p:commandButton` to submit the value from `p:inputText`

2) use `p:ajax event="keyup"` or `event="change"`,inside `p:inputText`

also take a look at the showcase [p:ajax enables ajax features on supported components.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml)

p.s , remove the `value` attribute from the `p:inplace` (there is no such attribute in `p:inplace`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the ajax event did the trick. I mixed up value and label while typing the question, luckily I had it right in my actual code.

Comment: your link  "p:ajax enables ajax behavior on any JSF component" refers to a not existing page. please change it

Answer (score 1):

Lets give your components `id`s:

```
<h:form id="someForm">
  <p:inputText id="first" value="#{myController.selectedBean.text}" />
  <p:inplace id="second" editor="true" value="#{myController.selectedBean.text}">
    <p:inputText id="third" value="#{myController.selectedBean.text}" />
  </p:inplace>
</h:form>
```

1. According to the [Primefaces Documentation 3.5](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf) the component `p:inplace` has no attribute called `value`.
2. Do you submit the form `someForm` when changing the value of `first`? Otherwise the updated values from `first` won't be passed to `MyController` and `MyBean`. `p:inplace` submits the values automatically whereby you have to do it yourself it you use the standard `p:inputText`.